# stack the 2nd element first and then the 3rd element

Tags: html, css

I have three divs. I want them to be in one line so I used inline-block. When I resize the window the third element (nav) stacks and then the 2nd element (searchBar). I want the 2nd element stacks first and then the 3rd one. For undoing, the 3rd element and then the 2nd element.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  min-eight: 48px;
  position: fixed;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fed700;
}

nav {
  width: 489.7px;
  height: 18px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

#searchBar {
  width: 330px;
  height: 16px;
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#logo {
  width: 220px;
  height: 32px;
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id=logo>logo
  </div>
  <div id=searchBar>searchBar
  </div>
  <nav>nav
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: The only way you can change the order is by using flexbox or JavaScript

Comment: You could use bootstrap if you want

Comment: This is some kind of difficult item since the width of the 3rd element greater than the second element. So while resizing the screen, third element will be always considered for the stacking

Comment: Do the elements all have fixed widths like that? If so, it'd be easy to devise a solution with media queries, since you'll know exactly when you want the wrapping to occur.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an inline-block wrapper with a min-width, wrapping the nav and searchBar. That would give the result you wanted in with the code sample supplied, but might cause problems in the real world, depending on your requirements.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 48px;
  position: fixed;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fed700;
}

.wrapper {
  min-width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
nav {
  width: 489.7px;
  height: 18px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

#searchBar {
  width: 330px;
  height: 16px;
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#logo {
  width: 220px;
  height: 32px;
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id=logo>logo
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
   <div id=searchBar>searchBar
   </div>
   <nav>nav
   </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```